# Want to take the difference of two columns in Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to take the difference of columns of a table.we have column name as Planned_date so now I Want to take the difference of these two columns

```
A = Planned_Date of stop1 - Planned_Date of stop5
```

So how I can write the query to fetch the value of A
below is the sample query I have written but somehow it is not working for me.

```
select (select planned_arrival as val1 
        from shipment_stop 
         where stop_num = 1 
         and shipment_gid = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.L171009358')
       -
      (select planned_arrival as val2 
       from shipment_stop 
       where stop_num = 5 
       and shipment_gid = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.L171009358')
```

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried to write the query just with (-) like below.

Comment: select (select planned_arrival as val1 from shipment_stop where stop_num = 
    1 and shipment_gid = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.L171009358')-
    (select planned_arrival as val2 from shipment_stop where stop_num = 5 and 
    shipment_gid = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.L171009358') from dual

Comment: My Question is how Can i get the value of A with the best possible way. Can we use cross join here?

Comment: If you want to get more than just this one difference, you could inner join Shipment_stop on itself with shipment_gid and a.Stop_num<>b.stop_num. That would tell you all of the times from stop to stop and from any stop to any other stop on the same shipment_gid

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
SELECT
    s1.planned_arrival - s2.planned_arrival AS val
FROM
    shipment_stop s1,
    shipment_stop s2
WHERE
    s1.stop_num = 1
    AND s2.stop_num = 5
    AND s1.shipment_gid = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.L171009358'
    AND s1.shipment_gid = s2.shipment_gid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should work with a `from` clause:

```
select (select planned_arrival as val1 
        from shipment_stop 
         where stop_num = 1 
         and shipment_gid = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.L171009358')
       -
      (select planned_arrival as val2 
       from shipment_stop 
       where stop_num = 5 
       and shipment_gid = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.L171009358')
from dual;
```

Personally, I would write this using conditional aggregation:

```
select (max(case when stop_num = 1 then planned_arrival end) -
        max(case when stop_num = 5 then planned_arrival end)
       )
from shipment_stop 
where stop_num in (1, 5) and 
      shipment_gid = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.L171009358';
```

Comment: Yeah it worked for me but one more question here. Planned_arrival is a Date so If I am using (-) it is giving the result as 3.03745637474747474 and it is not my expectation. so basically suppose Val1 is having 13-Oct-2017 and Val2 is having 10-Oct-2017 so if I am doing Val2 - Val1 then it should show 3 Days but looks like it is using the time also. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: To remove the time element just use `TRUNC()` on the date columns.